# Is converting Windows Form app to UWP app necessary for Win10 tablet?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, win-universal-app

We developed a `Windows Forms` application that was initially going to run in a `Windows 10` PC. At the last minute, it was changed to a `Windows 10` tablet so I assumed that it would not run correctly and that we would need to convert the whole app to a `Universal Windows Platform` (`UWP`) app.

So I sent the complete app to a user with a `Windows 10` tablet as a *zip* file. Lo and behold, he was able to run it in the tablet flawlessly.

This app will not be going to the Windows Store and we will only deploy the app to selected Windows 10 tablets the same way we did here (via zip file or similar format).

My question: Given our situation and the limited deployment of this app, is there any noticeable benefit to converting this Windows Forms app to a UWP app? Or most importantly, is there a reason why we *shouldn't* leave it as a Windows Forms app?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Benefit**:

If you convert your app to UWP, note that it won't be a simple port and you would be writing most stuff again due the difference in API, as the name suggests you will have a single app that runs on multiple device platforms of Windows family like tablet, phone, desktop etc.

**Otherwise**:

In your case, you won't be harmed if you continue with win forms app. That is obviously guaranteed to run on Win 10, it's not a surprise. I don't see any reason for putting development efforts again to create UWP unless you need aforementioned benefit.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues running your software on a tablet as long as it is the same architecture as a desktop pc aka x86 or x86_64.

UWP is designed to be sandboxed and distributed via the Windows store. There is nothing stopping your from distributing a desktop app in the age old tradition of installers and .zip files.

As for whether you should leave it as a windows forms app, some might argue that bringing it in-line with Microsofts more recent GUI family (aka XAML) would help future proof your product. While I think it is definately worth investigating, there is no real hard need to jump ship if you don't have too as I do not expect Microsoft will pull the WinForms platform away for some time.

Comment: Just adding some info, you might want to plan the software distribution method. If you are developing in UWP, your app can run on the latest (I guess most of the future device will be) Windows 10S. Winform might not be able, unless it is a Windows 10 Pro.